I am unable to find if the function is always positive or negative or neither
$f(x) = a_{1}\sin x + b_1 \cos x + a_2 \sin 2x + b_2 \cos 2x + \cdots + a_n\sin nx + b_n\cos nx$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$. All $a_i$'s and $b_i$'s are never simultaneously zero. Then
(A) $f(x) > 0$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ if all $a_i$'s and $b_i$'s are positive
(B) $f(x) < 0$ $\forall x  \in \mathbb{R}$ if all $a_i$'s and $b_i$'s are negative.
(C) $f(x)$ cannot have the same sign $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}.$
(D) None of (A), (B) & (C)
I tried to differentiate the function to see if it was increasing or decreasing, but it was useless. I thought of converting all $\sin(rx)$ and $\cos(rx)$ functions into only $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x), but it's getting complicated.

Look at the case $n=1$.

Did you ever hear of Fourier? :-)

@AnneBauval I'm not sure how I can come to an answer from that. For n=1, it could be any of the given options.

No. For $n=1$ it is C.

@AnneBauval oh right, my bad

$$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\sin(ix)+b_i\cos(ix)$$
We can modify $a_i\sin(ix)+b_i\cos(ix)$,(assuming both $a_i,b_i$ are positive).
$$a\sin(ix)+b\cos(ix)\\
=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\bigg(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\sin(ix)+\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\cos (ix)\bigg)$$
Let $\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\cos \phi$,so our expression becomes
$$=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}(\cos \phi \sin (ix)+\cos (ix) \sin \phi)\\
=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin(ix+\phi)$$
We know $\phi$ is always positive as range of $\cos^{-1}x$ is $[0,π]$.But this also helps us to study an information.
We come to know that if $x=2kπ,k\in \mathbb{Z}$ then expression is positive, $x=(2k+1)π$ then expression is negative for odd $i$ and positive for even $i$.
Thus $f(x)>0$ if $x=2kπ$, independent of $a_i,b_i$, and $f(x)<0 \ \text{or} \ f(x)>0$, depending upon $a_i,b_i$ if $x=(2k+1)$.
Thus (a) can't be the answer. We can prove that (b) isn't correct as well in a similar manner. (C) is infact correct, and the only correct option.

I believe like you that (C) is "in fact correct", i.e. that whatever the $(a_i,b_i)$'s ($\ne(0,0)$), $f$ cannot have a constant sign. But you did not prove it.

@AnneBauval By constant sign I understood that $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$, f(x) is either always negative or always positive. So didn't I prove that f(x) will not have a constant sign? I'm not arguing, I might have understood it wrong. Help will be appreciated

I don't think you understood anything wrong. By constant sign I understood the same as you. You did prove that A and B are false. You only conjecture C is correct. So do I but I have no clue.

@AnneBauval isn't proving A false imply that C is correct? (I'm very weak in logical reasoning though)

No, because in C you have no hypothesis on the signs of the $a_i$s and $b_i$s.

@AnneBauval oh now I see. You meant I need to prove that f(x) doesn't have constant sign for any $a_i,b_i$, negative or positive?

@AnneBauval Yes I think I proved it. f(x) can be both negative or positive in the case you're questioning. I'm taking a simple example of $x=π,a_i=b_i=1$. If $n$ is even, then f(x) is 0, if $n$ is odd, then f(x) is -1.

Sorry you are right for A and B, one counterexample suffices. For A you could just take $f(x)=\cos x+\sin x$.

Regarding proving C is correct, can I get some help...I can't frame it. Where should I start? @AnneBauval
